# How to apply a filter on jsonb array of objects - after aggregating?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, subquery, lateral-join

I have a the follow select statement:

```
SELECT 
    cards.*, 
    COUNT(cards.*) OVER() AS full_count, 
    p.printing_information 
FROM 
    cards
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         pr.card_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(pr)) AS printing_information
     FROM 
         printings pr
     GROUP BY 
         pr.card_id) p ON cards.card_id = p.card_id 
WHERE 
    ...
```

I would like to be able to query on `set_id` that is within the `printings` table. I tried to do this within my above select statement by including `pr.set_id` but it then required a `GROUP BY pr.card_id, pr.set_id` which then made a row per printing rather than having all printings within the `printing_information` sub-array.

Unless I can determine how to do above, is it possible to search within the `printing_information` array of jsonb?

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like:

```
WHERE p.printing_information->set_id = '123'
```

Unfortunately I can't do that as it's within an array.

What's the best way to achieve this? I could just do post-processing of the result to strip out unnecessary results, but I feel there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT cards.*
     , count(cards.*) over() AS full_count
     , p.printing_information
FROM   cards
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pr.card_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(pr)) AS printing_information
   FROM   printings pr
   WHERE  pr.set_id = '123'            -- HERE!
   GROUP  BY pr.card_id
   ) p ON cards.card_id = p.card_id
WHERE  ...
```

This is *much* cheaper than filtering after the fact. And can be supported with an index on `(set_id)` - unlike any attempts to filter on the dynamically generated `jsonb` column.

This is efficient, while we need to aggregate all or most rows from table `printings` anyway. But your added `WHERE  ...` implies more filters on the outer `SELECT`. If that results in only few rows from `printings` being needed, a `LATERAL` subquery should be more efficient:

```sql
SELECT cards.*
     , count(cards.*) OVER() AS full_count
     , p.printing_information
FROM   cards c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(pr)) AS printing_information
   FROM   printings pr
   WHERE  pr.card_id = c.card_id
   AND    pr.set_id = '123'    -- here!
   ) p
WHERE  ...  -- selective filter here?!?
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Aside, there is no "array of jsonb" here. The subquery produces a `jsonb` containing an array.

Comment: I would be interested actual performance results of both for a query with and one without selective outer filter in your db ...